# How to set alert for two 'value' by jQuery if the 'value' is equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set alert when the value is same. And the value selected is back to previous value
Here is my HTML:

```js
$("#to").val("BGK");
 var fromCity = "";
 var toCity = "";
   $('#from,#to').change(function(){
     var fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
     var toCityVal = $("#to").val();
       if (fromCityVal == toCityVal){
         alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");
         } 
         else {
           //here's problem, what should I do?
          $("#from").val();
         }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="from">
  <option value="DPS">Denpasar</option>
  <option value="BGK">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="MOS">Moscow</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="to">
  <option value="DPS">Denpasar</option>
  <option value="BGK">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="MOS">Moscow</option>
</select>
```

I try this, but not success, What should I do? or any suggestion? Thank you
Here's my code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/hx1voew9/

Comment: Fiddle works as expected!

Comment: what is the expected behavior? I didnt get your point

Comment: **And the value selected is back to previous value** what does this means?

Comment: I think he means `Else` instead of `And`

Comment: i think he means that when the duplicate value is selected, the selected option will be reset to previous value.

Comment: I mean when I change from Denpasar to Bangkok, alert is show up. And after I close alert, the value is back to Denpasar

Comment: @dediwibisono see my answer

Comment: Please find updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/hx1voew9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
$("#to").val("BGK");
            var $fromCityValOld = $("#from").val();
            var $toCityValOld = $("#to").val();
        $('#from,#to').change(function(){
    $fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
    $toCityVal = $("#to").val();
            if ($fromCityVal == $toCityVal){
        alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");
        $("#from").val($fromCityValOld);
                $("#to").val($toCityValOld);
            }  else {
       $fromCityValOld = $fromCityVal;
       $toCityValOld = $toCityVal;
      }

         });
```

working on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/josegallom/hx1voew9/9/)

Comment: Oh looking good, This is that what I need, Perfect! Thank you @Jose Gallo

Comment: You are wellcome :) @dedi wibisono have a nice day

Answer (score 4):

You must storage the previous value as a backup. You can make it with a focus event:

```
    $("#to").val("BGK");
    var item = '';
    var previous = '';
    $('#from,#to').on('focus', function () {
      previous = this.value;
      item = this;
    }). change(function(){
    var fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
            var toCityVal = $("#to").val();
            if (fromCityVal == toCityVal){
                alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");
                $(item).val(previous);
            } else {
                previous = this.value;
                $("#from").val();
            }
    })
```

This is the working fiddle:

```js
$("#to").val("BGK");

    var item = '';
    var previous = '';
    $('#from,#to').on('focus', function () {
      previous = this.value;
      item = this;
    }). change(function(){
    var fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
            var toCityVal = $("#to").val();
            if (fromCityVal == toCityVal){
                alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");
                $(item).val(previous);
            } else {
                previous = this.value;
            }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="from">
  <option value="DPS">Denpasar</option>
  <option value="BGK">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="MOS">Moscow</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="to">
  <option value="DPS">Denpasar</option>
  <option value="BGK">Bangkok</option>
  <option value="MOS">Moscow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh I have to storage the previous value. Thank you @megavexus

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fix . **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hx1voew9/1/)**

```
$("#to").val("BGK");

var fromCity;  // have global variables to backup your selection in case of same values
var toCity;

    $('#from,#to').on('focus', function() {
      fromCity = $("#from").val(); // on focus of the dropdown set the values into global variables
      toCity = $("#to").val();
    });

    $('#from,#to').change(function() {
      var fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
      var toCityVal = $("#to").val();
      if (fromCityVal == toCityVal) {
        alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");

        // from and to are same so reset the selection to its previous state.
        $("#from").val(fromCity);
        $("#to").val(toCity);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yess, it's work, Thank you @Reddy thanks for the comment line. Thats simple

Comment: @dediwibisono glad I was helpful. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

At page load , fetch your current selection values in a variable, and map the selection box with this value after alert.

Answer (score -1):

Please find the working fiddle as expected - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/hx1voew9/)

```
$('#from,#to').change(function() {
  var fromCityVal = $("#from").val();
  var toCityVal = $("#to").val();
  if (fromCityVal == toCityVal) {
    alert("city of origin may not be the same as the destination city!");
    $("#from").val("DPS");
    $("#to").val("BGK");
  }
});
```